# jqueryでtableの中身を上から読み込む(複数行)

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

jqueryでmodal上にあるテーブルを読み込み、 
一部のカラムをhtml上にtemplateで読み込ませて表示させたいです。 
今のところ、eachを使えば読み込めると思ったのですが 
tableの最終行しか読み込まれませんでした。
　　　これは参考にしたURLです
    [jqueryで要素のある順に番号をつける](http://h2ham.seesaa.net/article/114037411.html)

```
//コード
function allsave(){
  var mtllgh = $("#mtlc tbody").children().length;
  $("#mtlc tr").each(function(){
    $(this).children().each(function(i){
      v1 = $('[name=m-name] option:selected').text();
      v2 = $('[name=m-num] option:selected').text();
      var resultone = {
        val1 : "",
        val2 : "",
        val3 : "",
        val4 : "",
        val5 : "",
        val6 : "",
        val7 : v1 + "  " + v2,
        val8 : $('#hm').val(),
        val9 : $('.size1').val() + " x "  + $('.size2').val() + " " + $('.kazu').val() + "個"
      }
      var result = {
        val1 : "",
        val2 : "",
        val3 : "",
        val4 : "",
        val5 : "",
        val6 : "",
        val7 : v1 + "  " + v2,
        val8 : $('#hm').val(),
        val9 : $('.size1').val() + " x " + $('.size2').val() + " " + $('.kazu').val() + "個"
      }
      if(i!=0){
        $("#showltbl1").html(addmtbl(result));
      }else{
        $("#showltbl1").html(addmtbl(resultone));
      }
      i = i+1;
    });
  });
}
//
```

Comment: 該当のtableのHTMLもご提示ください。

Answer (score 1):

addmtbl()が、どのような処理をしているか不明ですが、addmtbl()が単純に文字列を返す関数なら
.html(addmtbl(result))では エレメント内にaddmtbl(result)が返した文字列で、上書きしてしまいます。

回しながら追加するには、.append　を使います。
例　$("#showltbl1").append(addmtbl(result));

```js
$(function(){
        $('#ow1').on('click',function(){
            $("#showltbl1").html('<p> 上書き </p>');
        })
        $('#ad1').on('click',function(){
            $("#showltbl1").append('<p> 追加</p>');
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ow1">上書き</button>　<button id="ad1">追加</button>
<div id="showltbl1"></div>
```